# htaccess redirecting to query URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am using following rule for pages e.g. domain.com/item means get item page and URL should be visible as domain.com/item only.
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

domain.com/item was working fine until few days back but now it redirects to domain.com/item/?page=item.
When I try to open some other page e.g. domain.com/otherpage it is working fine and it is showing domain.com/otherpage only and not redirecting.

The issue is happening only with **item** page.

When I am using **domain.com/item/** it is not redirecting and working correctly and showing domain.com/item/ (though I will not be using /, this I used for testing purpose only).

How to correct this issue?

Comment: Do you have any physically existing file or folder named `item` or `item.(suffix)` on the root level? If so, try disabling `MultiViews`.

Comment: Just checked item folder was present on root level (created by mistake). After removing it things are working fine. Thanks for providing solution.